# Salesforce notification open count track issue for flutter apps salesforce

Tags: push-notification, salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have implemented Flutter apps and have bound the code using method channel for android and ios.

- Mobile push open count is not tracking after sending notification from the salesforce to android and ios.

I have tried all the following links but didn't work for me.
https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/analytics/analytics.html
https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/
https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/notifications/customize-notifications.html

minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 34
compileSdkVersion 34